# What is the CreateCriteria equiv of this line of code:

Tags: nhibernate

_session.CreateQuery("Select a.AuLname From Authors a Order By a.AuLname")
   .List();

I must be drawing a blank here...but I cannot figure out how to return a list of author last names using the session's CreateCriteria method. Getting a distinct list of last names is not a problem as I can use a projection. But that is not what I am trying to do here.

TIA...

JP

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
_session.CreateCriteria<Author>()
   .SetProjection(Projections.Property("AuLname"))
   .AddOrder(Order.Asc("AuLname"))
   .List();
```

Comment: Thanks Markus. That quite didn't do it...but you gave me something to talk about. Projection was definitly it - and it makes sense since we are projecting something to the list. This worked:

_session.CreateCriteria(typeof (Authors))
                .SetProjection(Projections.Property("AuLname"))
                .AddOrder(Order.Asc("AuLname"))
                .List<string>();

Comment: Your answer prompted me to put up a quick whitepaper on my blog:
http://johnvpetersen.com/?p=61